# Android Eclipse Program Error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

I just created a new Android project in Eclipse IDE, clicked on finish, and before even running project can see error symbol on project folder in eclipse IDE. If I expand folders, I don't see any red cross mark on any of files, can you please help me out. If I run as android project it says "Your project contains error(s), please fix them before using your application" . I am puzzled, it was a fresh project. Tried deleting and creating another project , restarting eclipse. Nothing works. Can you please help me out. Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of times Eclipse will fail to build Android projects properly. This might be eclipse.. it might be Eclipse's Android plugin. I'm not really sure. The way I get around it is by selecting from the menu Project > Clean... > Select the project giving you problems and hit ok. This will clear all built files and force it to rebuild, often fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the project itself, like the classpath or something. Go to Window > Show View > Problems (you may have to choose Other..., if so you will find it in the General section). In the Problems view it should give you more info. If you still can't figure it out post what the text from the Problem view.